# Celery worker raise ImportError when using Django as the broker and the result backend

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I want to run celery in my development machine with the django as both the Broker and Result Backend (using djcelery). i followed the getting started instructions from the celery documentation but when i run the command:

```
celery -A excelery worker -l info
```

i got this stack trace on my console. it says that the django settings module couldn't be loaded but i don't now why.

i am using celery 3.1.4, djcelery 3.1.1 and Django 1.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-3.3.0.7-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\
forking.py", line 457, in main
self = load(from_parent)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
value = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\app\utils.py
", line 170, in _unpickle_app_v2
return cls(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\app\base.py"
, line 136, in __init__
symbol_by_name(fixup)(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\fixups\djang
o.py", line 39, in fixup
return DjangoFixup(app).install()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\fixups\djang
o.py", line 50, in __init__
self._db = import_module('django.db')
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 83, in <modul
e>
signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 88, i
n connect
if settings.DEBUG:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __ge
tattr__
self._setup(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49, in _set
up
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __i
nit__
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'excelery.settings' (Is it on sys.path? I
s there an import error in the settings file?): cannot import name close_old_con
nections
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard-3.3.0.7-py2.7-win32.egg\billiard\
forking.py", line 457, in main
self = load(from_parent)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
value = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\app\utils.py
", line 170, in _unpickle_app_v2
return cls(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\app\base.py"
, line 136, in __init__
symbol_by_name(fixup)(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\fixups\djang
o.py", line 39, in fixup
return DjangoFixup(app).install()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-3.1.4-py2.7.egg\celery\fixups\djang
o.py", line 50, in __init__
self._db = import_module('django.db')
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 83, in <modul
e>
signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 88, i
n connect
if settings.DEBUG:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __ge
tattr__
self._setup(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49, in _set
up
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __i
nit__
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'excelery.settings' (Is it on sys.path? I
s there an import error in the settings file?): cannot import name close_old_con
nections
[2013-11-23 16:34:06,471: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-2' pid:2332 exited
with exitcode 1
```

Comment: Please try upgrading to 3.1.5, and make sure that you use the new `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)` way to do things from the updated tutorial at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Ok.Thanks. it seems that this is solved in celery 3.1.5. but running it on windows raised another exception. that was the problem of os.getegid() which is not exists in windows. upgrading to the development version of celery solved this too.